I was installing Jupyter notebook and got a message in Command Prompt maybe something related to file path. Help me fix this please?
"'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
This is the error message I get whenever I try to run Jupyter notebook.
I earlier got a message saying this file is not on file path ,consider adding this several times.
I think installation is done but the file path is not added . So how do I di it?
I dont know how to add it to file path .
I am expecting you someone will help me add it to the file path

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjupyter-notebook%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file

Try adding Scripts folder to environment variables
search environment
click on this search result
click on environment variables at the lower right part of the window,
double click "Path" row and a new window will pop up
add your scripts folder path in a new row, usually -
"C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts"
then restart the shell
